# Manipulate Google Analytic data

Tags: asp.net, api, google-analytics

I able to fetch data from google analytic api.How I get combination of data like country wise page visit.I try:

```
 var query1 = asv.Data.Ga.Get("ga:xxxxxxxx", startDate, endDate, "ga:pageviews,ga:country");
  query1.Metrics = "ga:country";//Gives error(can not be assigned to -- it is read only.)
  query1.Dimensions = "ga:country";
  query1.Sort = "ga:country,ga:pageviews";
  query1.StartIndex = 1;
  var report1 = query1.Fetch();
```

I want to fetch record and bind in a grid.Where is my mistake.If I comment that line
`query1.Fetch();` gives error means unable to get record.
When I use

`var request = asv.Data.Ga.Get("ga:xxxxxxxx", startDate, endDate, "ga:visits,ga:pageviews,ga:bounces");`

Its successfully get a record.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get a solution so I post it for future reference.

```
  var query1 = asv.Data.Ga.Get("ga:63104444", startDate, endDate, "ga:visits");

  query1.Dimensions = "ga:country";
  query1.Sort = "-ga:visits";

  var report1 = query1.Fetch();

  List<KeyValuePair<string, object>> CountryWiseVisitList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>();
  foreach (IList<string> lstRow in report1.Rows)
  {
    CountryWiseVisitList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>(lstRow[0].ToString(), lstRow[1].ToString()));            
   }
   gdvCountryWiseVisit.DataSource = CountryWiseVisitList; //Bind on grid
   gdvCountryWiseVisit.DataBind();
```